# How do I have a URL with params and a url_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm just trying to setup excel downloading option for my site. All I want to do is:

```
<%= link_to 'Export', export_to_excel_path(:param => @item.id), url_for(:format => 'xls') %>
```

I want to give my user a link to export to excel, with the additional param. I get the following error:

```
undefined method `stringify_keys' for "/controller/show.xls":String
```

I need to use url_for because in export_to_excel, I have a

```
respond_to
```

in order to respond with a .xls MIME type file. I am using the to_xls gem, and everything works fine except that I'm not able to figure out this link.

Comment: Try: `<%= link_to 'Export', export_to_excel_path(:param => @item.id, :format => 'xls') %>`

Comment: um. I am an idiot. thanks a lot jdoe, it is really early in the AM and I for some reason thought I had already attempted that and failed. Added as a solution to this & closed. Thanks guys.

Comment: Hi @jdoe, could you please copy your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All credit to jdoe:

```
 <%= link_to 'Export', export_to_excel_path(:param => @item.id, :format => 'xls') %>
```

Comment: Hi -- proper SO etiquette is to ask @jdoe to copy his comment to an answer, then accept it with the green checkmark.  jdoe will get the points, and other users will be able to see the accepted answer.